# Custom HTML attribute requires a custom helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to create a form with some custom data attributes on the inputs:

```
<input type="text" data-family="Dinosaurs">
```

This seemed like a nice clean way to have easy front-end access (haha!) with jquery:

```
$("[data-family='Dinosaurs']").doSomething()
```

The problem is I can't get Rails (3.0.3) to render the attribute.

```
<%= f.text_field :question, :id=>"poll_question", :class=>"BigInput", :style=>"width:98%;", :attributes=>"data-submit_clear='1'" %>
```

I've tried many permutations to no avail and can't find an example of how to do this.  Do I need to modify the `text_field` helper to support any custom attributes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Oops.  It's just

```
<%= f.text_field :question, :id=>"poll_question", :class=>"BigInput", :style=>"width:98%;", 'data-submit_clear'=>'1' %>
```

Answer (score 20):

Rails >3.1 has a handy shortcut for data-attributes like this which most HTML-generating helpers support:

```
<%= f.text_field :question, :data => { :submit_clear => '1' } %>
```

It can make things more readable when you have a couple of data attributes, e.g.:

```
<%= f.text_field :question, :data => { :submit_clear => '1', :more_info => 'Ok', :also => 'this' } %>
```